# wiring properties with spring's p namespace doesn't work

Tags: spring, jakarta-ee

I'm trying wiring properties with spring's p namespace. The problem is I got "org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: (...) cvc-complex-type.3.2.2: Attribute 'p:instrument-ref' is not allowed to appear in element 'bean'."

Please look at my xml, classes and tell me what I'm doing wrong.

performers.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

    <bean id="guitar" class="com.competition.Guitar"></bean>

    <bean id="instrumentalist" class="com.competition.Instrumentalist"
    p:instrument-ref="guitar" p:song="some song">
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Instrumentalist.java:

```
package com.competition;

public class Instrumentalist implements Performer {

    private Instrument instrument;
    private String song;

    public Instrument getInstrument() {
        return instrument;
    }

    public void setInstrument(Instrument instrument) {
       this.instrument = instrument;
    }

    public String getSong() {
        return song;
    }

    public void setSong(String song) {
        this.song = song;
    }

    public void perform() {
        System.out.println("Playing " + song);
        instrument.play();

    }

}
```

Guitar.java:

```
package com.competition;

public class Guitar implements Instrument {

    public void play() {
        System.out.println("play on guitar");
    }
```

}

Comment: Your code runs fine using Spring 3.0.5-RELEASE and 3.2.2-RELEASE. What version are you using?

Comment: Thank you! This was the problem. I had older version of Spring. When I change the version of Spring in my pom.xml code works fine.

Comment: You did me a favour. Despite having used Spring for several years, I had never come across the p: or c: namespaces